# Klist error: Bad format in credentials cache

Tags: kerberos, keytab

I am seeing the following error when inspecting a newly created keytab:

> [rxie@cedgedev02 ~]$ klist rxie.keytab klist: Bad format in
>   credentials cache (filename: rxie.keytab)
>
> [rxie@cedgedev02 ~]$ kinit -kt rxie.keytab kinit: Cannot determine
>   realm for host (principal host/cedgedev02.company.com@)

Note I replaced the company's name here.

The keytab was created with a customized python file which wraps the actual ktutil commands below:

```
addent -password -p rxie@COMPANY.COM -k 1 -e rc4-hmac
addent -password -p rxie@COMPANY.COM -k 1 -e aes256-cts
```

Can any one share your thought on where/what is missing here? Thank you very much.

Comment: RTFM: to inspect a keytab file, instead of a credentials cache, `klist -k dummy.keytab -e`

Comment: RTFM: a keytab may contain passwords for multiple users, hence `kinit` does not "guess" the UPN > `kinit -kt rxie.keytab rxie@COMPANY.COM`

Comment: RTF MIT Kerberos M: you need to enter a whole lot of params in `/etc/krb5.conf` including the default realm, the mapping rules from domain and/or server names to realms, possibly the cross-realm trust relationships, etc etc

Comment: Also, you need a tight DNS config with consistent forward and reverse lookups; and always use _canonical_ DNS names (not aliases -- and no proxy or load balancer in between) ideally case-sensitive...

Comment: Thank you, would you please put your comment together into an answer? I will accept it.

Answer (score 2):

The working command is:

```
kinit -kt rxie.keytab rxie
```